# Programmatically detect class parameters

Tags: class, c#-4.0, generics, types

In C# I have a function that accepts `<T>`. Currently I am creating an instance using `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.

Is there a way to detect the parameters of `<T>` at run time so I can create `<T>` with parameters?

Method stub is like below:

```
public static T Get<T>()
{
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "a function that accepts `<T>`". You can certainly find the parameters which are part of the various constructors of a type, but you'd still need values for those parameters...

Comment: I already know how I am going to get the values, I simple just need to know the types of values it is going to need. Edited my question to show the function stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bear in mind that any particular type can have multiple constructors. You can find them all easily enough though:

```
var constructors = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
```

Note that [`Type.GetConstructors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructors.aspx) has an overload taking a `BindingFlags` in case you want to find non-public constructors.

Comment: Thanks a million, my custom dependency injection container is now finished.